# Count spaces in text (treat consecutive spaces as one)

Tags: python, python-3.x, spaces

How would you count the number of spaces or new line charaters in a text in such a way that consecutive spaces are counted only as one?
For example, this is very close to what I want:

```
string = "This is an  example text.\n   But would be good if it worked."
counter = 0
for i in string:
    if i == ' ' or i == '\n':
        counter += 1
print(counter)
```

However, instead of returning with `15`, the result should be only `11`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The default [str.split()](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) function will treat consecutive runs of spaces as one. So simply split the string, get the size of the resulting list, and subtract one.

`len(string.split())-1`

Comment: That's a clever solution, but sacrifices code clarity.

Comment: This fails for `string = "This is an  example text.\n     But would be good if it worked.   "` or any line ending in whitespace, the correct answer is 12, you need `len(string.split()) - (not string[-1].isspace())`

Answer (score 5):

Assuming you are permitted to use Python regex;

```
import re
print len(re.findall(ur"[ \n]+", string))
```

Quick and easy!

UPDATE: Additionally, use `[\s]` instead of `[ \n]` to match any whitespace character.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this:

```
string = "This is an  example text.\n   But would be good if it worked."
counter = 0
# A boolean flag indicating whether the previous character was a space
previous = False 
for i in string:
    if i == ' ' or i == '\n': 
        # The current character is a space
        previous = True # Setup for the next iteration
    else:
        # The current character is not a space, check if the previous one was
        if previous:
            counter += 1

        previous = False
print(counter)
```

Answer (score 3):

`re` to the `re`scue.

```
>>> import re
>>> string = "This is an  example text.\n   But would be good if it worked."
>>> spaces = sum(1 for match in re.finditer('\s+', string))
>>> spaces
11
```

This consumes minimal memory, an alternative solution that builds a temporary list would be

```
>>> len(re.findall('\s+', string))
11
```

If you only want to consider space characters and newline characters (as opposed to tabs, for example), use the regex `'(\n| )+'` instead of `'\s+'`.

Comment: Does this take care of newlines?

Comment: @th3an0maly yes it does.

Answer (score 2):

Just store a character that was the last character found. Set it to i each time you loop. Then within your inner if, do not increase the counter if the last character found was also a whitespace character.

Answer (score 2):

You can iterate through numbers to use them as indexes.

```
for i in range(1, len(string)):
    if string[i] in ' \n' and string[i-1] not in ' \n':
        counter += 1
if string[0] in ' \n':
    counter += 1
print(counter)
```

Pay attention to the first symbol as this constuction starts from the second symbol to prevent `IndexError`.

Comment: indexing into string[-1] is probably not the best idea

Comment: and the result of this is also 15, not only 11.

Comment: Excuse me, I messed up the index. The part after `and` should be indexed as `i-1`, not `-1`

Answer (score 2):

You can use *enumerate*, checking the next char is not also whitespace so consecutive whitespace will only count as 1:

```
string = "This is an  example text.\n   But would be good if it worked."

print(sum(ch.isspace() and not string[i:i+1].isspace() for i, ch in enumerate(string, 1)))
```

You can also use `iter` with a generator function, keeping track of the last character and comparing:

```
def con(s):
    it = iter(s)
    prev = next(it)
    for ele in it:
        yield prev.isspace() and not ele.isspace()
        prev = ele
    yield ele.isspace()

print(sum(con(string)))
```

An itertools version:

```
string = "This is an  example text.\n     But would be good if it worked.  "

from itertools import tee, izip_longest

a, b = tee(string)
next(b)
print(sum(a.isspace() and not b.isspace() for a,b in izip_longest(a,b, fillvalue="") ))
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
def word_count(my_string):     
    word_count = 1
    for i in range(1, len(my_string)):
        if my_string[i] == " ":

            if not my_string[i - 1] == " ":    
                word_count += 1

         return word_count
```

Comment: Please format your code (make function definition formatted as well) and provide a few words about your solution and results (on some example data).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the function `groupby()` to find groups of consecutive spaces:

```
from collections import Counter
from itertools import groupby

s = 'This is an  example text.\n   But would be good if it worked.'

c = Counter(k for k, _ in groupby(s, key=lambda x: ' ' if x == '\n' else x))
print(c[' '])
# 11
```